# How to condition your neural network to seek a specific amount of output?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, forecast

I transformed a time series with collection values ​​from `0 to 100` into a windows of 60 elements with `averages and standard deviation`, and counts `0-20 ... 80-100` of the next 30 readings, where each minute represents a collection, in a space timeless.

**Example:**

1 - Divide the data into blocks of 60 elements, where each new block it moves 10 elements

*Example: 0 to 60, 10 to 70, 20 to 80 ... etc*

2 - Then divide the blocks into 5 parts (12x5 = 60)

3 - Calculate [average](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.average.html) and [deviation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html#:%7E:text=The%20standard%20deviation%20is%20the,N%20%3D%20len(x)%20.) of each part

4 - Take the next 30 elements from each block of 60 elements

*Example: 60 to 90, 70 to 100, 80 to 110 ... etc*

5 - Calculate how many readings there are from 0 to 100, grouping every 20

*Example: 0 to 20, 20 to 40, 40 to 60, 60 to 80 and 80 to 100*

> (0 to 20) 12,18,11,14 = 4
> (20 to 40) 20,25,23 = 3
> ...

The result would be a dataframe like this:

[image]

6 - I collect the largest element of each column and divide all elements of the column by it, generating binary values (0,1):

My X consists of `mean1,std1 ... mean5,std5`

My Y consists of `0-20 ... 80-100`

Learning model:

```
cvscores = []
for train, test in kfold.split(X,Y):

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10,
                kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001),
                kernel_initializer=VarianceScaling(), 
                activation='sigmoid',
                name='hidden-input'))
    model.add(Dense(5, 
                kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001),
                kernel_initializer=VarianceScaling(),                 
                activation='sigmoid',
                name='output'))
    
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])
    
    model.fit(X.iloc[train].values, Y.iloc[train].values, epochs=100, batch_size=5, verbose = 0,
              validation_data=(X.iloc[test].values, Y.iloc[test].values))

    scores = model.evaluate(X.iloc[test].values, Y.iloc[test].values, verbose=0)
    print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
    cvscores.append(scores[1] * 100)

print("%.2f%% (+/- %.2f%%)" % (np.mean(cvscores), np.std(cvscores)))

y = model.predict(X)
```

To finish the process I take the values ​​of `y` multiplied by the division values ​​of step 6, receiving this output:

[image]

**This neural network aims to answer the following question:** *In the next 60 readings, how many peaks of 80-100 will happen?*

My question is: how to use this model to have an output of the next 60 readings?

*Example: `model.predict(X) = 60 readings`*

```
Index:  | 0  | 1  | ... | 58  | 59  |
        ------------------------------
Output: | 24 | 26 | ... | 42  | 45  |
```

The shape it is in today gives me an output with 1003 lines the size of my data set, I would like to limit this network to working in search of only the next 60 readings, any suggestions?

Comment: I don't really understand your data nor your output. What do you mean by 60 readings? I think you are trying to fit a sequence to sequence problem into a dense neural network which wont work. If you have variable input or output length you should read about recurrent neural networks(RNN).

Comment: let me clarify, ask me questions

Comment: I tried to improve the question, check, please!